# jquery loading and setTimeout problems

Tags: jquery, settimeout

I am loading this page with .load() and the timeout is 500, but when the textarea is focused, I want to timeout to be changed to 5000000. This code isn't working.

```
function refreshTable(){
    var t = 500;
    $('#postHolder').load('postFrame.php', function(){
     $("textarea").focusin(function() {
        var t = 5000000;
             });
    setTimeout(refreshTable, t);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't change a timeout by changing the variable that was used to specify the time when the timeout was started. You need to stop the timeout and start a new one with the time that you want:

```
function loadPost(){
  $('#postHolder').load('postFrame.php', function(){
    $("textarea").focusin(function() {
      clearTimeout(timer);
      timer = setTimeout(refreshTable, 5000000);
    });
    var timer = setTimeout(refreshTable, 500);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're close, but you're doing two things wrong:

- resetting `t` every time your function runs. Your focus handler is setting it to 5000000, then the function runs and the first line sets it back to 500.
- using `var` down in the lower scope (inside the focus handler). this causes a "new t" variable to get created in that lower scope, separate from the higher-up one

You could just move `t` up a level, and remove `var` from the lower scope, and it works in my tests:

```
var t = 500;
function refreshTable(){
    $('#postHolder').load('postFrame.php', function(){
         $("textarea").focusin(function() {
             t = 5000000;
         });
         setTimeout(refreshTable, t);
    });
}
```

Here's a fiddle with the `.load` method taken out, should be the same idea: http://jsfiddle.net/8yx6P/